# Json from the dom not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

Why is my JSON not working? I tried

In the dom and js I have:

```
<div class="compare-table-data" data-compare-table='
{
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        },
    },
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        },
    }
}'></div>

    var jsonArray = $('.compare-table-data').data('compare-table'),
            table = '';


        for (var item in jsonArray){
            table += item["naam"];
        }
    }

    $("#compareTable").append(table);
```

Result... a whole lot of: undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

Comment: `JSON.parse()` it before using.

Comment: It seems your JSON has some issues... it should be [{},{}]... not {{},{}}

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  `[...]When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string;[...]` [jQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Beside that the JSON is not valid: a `for ... in`  iterates over the `keys` not the values [MDN: for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic Indeed Op's json is invalid. But suggesting `JSON.parse` is an addition info to him. He could think about it when he tries to access a string as an object in future. And that wouldn't answer his question.

Comment: `$('.compare-table-data').data('compareTable');`

Answer (score 1):

your JSON was incorrect it should be array of objects,
and `for in` loop should be used to loop through object nt array,
`for` is better here

```
<div class="compare-table-data" data-compare-table='
[
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        }
    },
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        }
    }
]'></div>

    var jsonArray = $('.compare-table-data').data('compare-table'),
            table = '';
        jsonArray = $.parseJSON(jsonArray );


        for (var i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
            table += jsonArray[i]["naam"];
        }
    }

    $("#compareTable").append(table);
```

Comment: Hey Riaz, I have tried this, but I get the next error in my console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON

Comment: There ws some extra `,` in the json i'v removed it try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should change {} braces to [] as you have an array, remove unnecessary commas inside the JSON, change for-in loop (used to iterate over properties of an object) to for-of (used to iterate over elements of an array)

```
<div class="compare-table-data" data-compare-table='[
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        }
    },
    {
        "naam":"Ford",
        "id":"BMW",
        "eig":{
            "test":"wert"
        }
    }
]'></div>

var jsonArray = $('.compare-table-data').data('compare-table'), table = '';
for (var item of jsonArray){
    table += item["naam"];
}
$("#compareTable").append(table);
```